# Decoupling an ASP.NET MVC application from Entity Framework

Tags: asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, entity-framework-4.1, separation-of-concerns

If I have this project structure

- Foo.Data

  - reference EntityFramework
- Foo.Business

  - reference Foo.Data
- Foo.Web

  - reference Foo.Business

Isn't that supposed to allow me to prevent adding a reference to EntityFramework from Foo.Web?

How can I call `System.Data.Entity.Database.SetInitializer()` from my `global.asax.cs` without adding the EntityFramework reference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you can do is create a `InitializeDatabase()` function in your `Foo.Business` project which in-turn calls `System.Data.Entity.Database.SetInitializer()`. You can then call `InitializeDatabase()` from your `Foo.Web` project which already has a reference to `Foo.Business`

Comment: Can you elaborate on why/how it didn't work? What error did you get?

Comment: I figured it out. I was injecting it incorrectly. This approach worked.

Answer (score 3):

Why do you want to?

The reason you're doing this uncoupling is (I assume) to enable you to switch out the data tier at a later point, without having to modify anything in the Web project, and as little as possible in the Business project. To accomplish this, you should make sure that all your classes work against *interfaces*, rather than against concrete implementations.

In your example, you should probably define a `Repository` interface of some sort, which includes an `Initialize()` method. You then create a class (perhaps your specialized DbContext) implement the interface, and you work against that. In the `Initialize()` method on your repository, you call `Database.SetInitializer()` and thus you never have to reference System.Data.Entity in either the web or business projects.

Answer (score 2):

Nope. If Foo.Web needs classes in EntityFramework, it will have to reference it. References don't cascade between projects.